# ConnectedRouter from react-router-redux does not support children props

Tags: react-router-v4, react-router-redux

While

```
<Router history={browserHistory} children={this.props.routes} />
```

is supported in React router v4,

using react-router-redux ConnectedRouter does not support it

for example

```
<ConnectedRouter
    history={this.props.history}
    children={this.props.routes}
/>
```

is there a way to pass routes as children props, since this is easy way to build routes with objects

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you should crete your app component inside

```
<ConnectedRouter history={history}>
  <div>
    <App />
  </div>
</ConnectedRouter>
```

your app component should handle the child components with the **switch** and **Route** elements,
something like :

```
<Switch> {/* redirect to the first correct statemet */}
   <Route path={NavigationPath.Home} component={Home} />
   <Route path={NavigationPath.About} component={About} />
   <Route path={NavigationPath.Summary} component={Summary} />
   <Route path={NavigationPath.Account} component={Login} />
   <Redirect from="/" to={NavigationPath.Home} />
   <Route component={NotFound} />
</Switch>
```

than you have child components with routes

Comment: I am not intersted in handling children like this when react-router completely fine handles children object routes...

Comment: take a look at this example will help you https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux

Comment: I do not have a problem recreating everything, it's not something I do not understand but if I spent X time making something that makes sense and it works with core package it should work with also package built on top of it,
thanks for your time but I think we are going in wrong direction....

looking now at react-router source and how it processes children prop

Answer (score 0):

you could map the object to components like they do in the docs:

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// then our route config
const routes = [
  { path: '/sandwiches',
    component: Sandwiches
  },
  { path: '/tacos',
    component: Tacos,
    routes: [
      { path: '/tacos/bus',
        component: Bus
      },
      { path: '/tacos/cart',
        component: Cart
      }
    ]
  }
]

// wrap <Route> and use this everywhere instead, then when
// sub routes are added to any route it'll work
const RouteWithSubRoutes = (route) => (
  <Route path={route.path} render={props => (
    // pass the sub-routes down to keep nesting
    <route.component {...props} routes={route.routes}/>
  )}/>
)

const RouteConfigExample = () => (
  <Router>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li><Link to="/tacos">Tacos</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/sandwiches">Sandwiches</Link></li>
      </ul>

      {routes.map((route, i) => (
        <RouteWithSubRoutes key={i} {...route}/>
      ))}
    </div>
  </Router>
)
```

From here: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/route-config

Comment: yea, this makes more sense, I figured out I can basically run the object and create my routes... I will try and let you know how it goes!

Comment: haha, ok for now, react-router actually provides opposite function  createRoutesFromReactChildren that converts routes you supply as React components as object :) not the opposite ...  you can import this easily from import { createRoutesFromReactChildren } from 'react-router' :)

Comment: I just found this https://github.com/reacttraining/react-router/tree/master/packages/react-router-config which lets you configure static routes for react router v4 - not sure if that helps